# Why is np nan convertible to int by `astype` (but not by `int`)?

Tags: python, numpy, integer, nan

This question comes from a finding that is very much not intuitive to me. If one tries the following:

```py
import numpy as np
print(np.array([np.nan]).astype(int))
print(int(np.array([np.nan])))
```

then the output of the first is `[-9223372036854775808]`, and the second raises `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`. I'd expect the later behaviour, and I'd definitely not expect that one can convert `np.nan` to an int. Why is this like that? Why can one use `astype` to convert `np.nan` to int? Does it have any functionality or meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) has optional argument `casting` whose default value is `'unsafe'`. Following values are allowed

- ‘no’ means the data types should not be cast at all.
- ‘equiv’ means only byte-order changes are allowed.
- ‘safe’ means only casts which  can preserve values are allowed.
- ‘same_kind’ means only safe casts or casts within a kind, like float64 to float32, are allowed.
- ‘unsafe’ means any data conversions may be done.

When one attempt to do

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array([np.nan]).astype(int, casting="safe"))
```

one gets following error

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('float64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. One more piece is missing - is there a reason why the default would be set to `unsafe`, ie. is there a reason why one would want to have it as a default behaviour? Because it goes against the explicit/implicit and errors should never pass silently zen of python, no?

Comment: @MyWork according to linked docs *Defaults to ‘unsafe’ for backwards compatibility.*